# Storm deploying error

Tags: database, apache-storm

I was trying to setup up Storm and 
I got stuck in step 3 where I got  many many errors like this:
Could not find artifact storm:libthrift7:jar:0.7.0 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
Could not transfer artifact storm:libthrift7:jar:0.7.0 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): Checksum validation failed, could not read expected checksum: GET request of: storm/libthrift7/0.7.0/libthrift7-0.7.0.jar.sha1 from clojars failed
Could not find artifact storm:libthrift7:jar:0.7.0 in jclouds-snapshot

Any ideas whats going wrong here ?

Comment: kindly provide more details like what is your environment, versions, how exactly you are installing the storm, should be much easier for others to get the root cause behind this

Comment: No clue about your problem without more details but you could have a look at [this article][1] for "one-click" Storm installs.


  [1]: http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/03/17/wirbelsturm-one-click-deploy-storm-kafka-clusters-with-vagrant-puppet/

Comment: So I am using https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy/wiki to deploy storm. I am downloading the lein script, putting it inside storm-deploy folder after cloning it from git.Then  I am putting the path to the storm-deploy in $PATH variable and making it executable.So the lein script is inside my storm-deploy folder and then I run lein deps and get a bunch of errors as mentioned above